# techincal foul before tipoff

Tags: basketball

When a technical foul occurs before tipoff how does that change the start of game procedures throughout each of the different levels of basketball, and who is considered as having first possession for the possesion arrow in leagues which use possession arrows?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, if team A is awarded a technical foul prior to the start of the game, team B shoots free-throws before tip-off.

[Rule 12, Section V, Letter J of the NBA rules](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_12.html?nav=ArticleList) state:

> Free throws awarded for a technical foul must be attempted by a
>   player in the game when the technical foul is assessed.
>
> (1) If a substitute has been beckoned into the game or has been
>   recognized by the officials as being in the game prior to a technical
>   foul being assessed, he is eligible to attempt the free throw(s).
>
> (2) **If the technical foul is assessed before the opening tap, any
>   player listed in the scorebook as a starter is eligible to attempt the
>   free throw(s).**
>
> (3) If a technical foul is assessed before the starting lineup is
>   indicated, any player on the squad may attempt the free throw(s).